# Python lxml library fails to parse &lt; and &gt;

Tags: javascript, python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an XSLT with javascript in it which uses "&lt ;" and "&gt ;" inside for loop

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function example() {
        var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; trs.length; i++) {
    }
      }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am using PYTHON LXML library to generate HTML using XSLT and XML.

```
import lxml.etree as ET
xml = ET.parse('sample.xml')
xslt = ET.parse('sample.xsl')
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
content = transform(xml)
f = open('output.html','w')
f.write(ET.tostring(content , pretty_print=True))
f.close()
```

But LXML is unable to replace special characters in the output HTML file

&lt ; to '<' and &gt ; to '>'

Is there any standard practice using LXML to replace "&lt ;" to '<' ?

To over come this issue I have to write another piece of code before writing to the file.

```
content = content.replace("&gt;", ">")
content = content.replace("&lt;", "<")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to decode/convert HTML entities, you should use `method="html"` in `tostring()` call:

```
ET.tostring(content, method="html", pretty_print=True)
```

or:

```
lxml.html.tostring(content, pretty_print=True)
```

DEMO:

```
from lxml import etree


text = """<html>
  <body>
    <script> 1 &lt; 2 </script>
  </body>
</html>
"""

tree = etree.fromstring(text)
print etree.tostring(tree, method="html")
```

prints:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script> 1 < 2 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've noticed this trick only works only if the tag is "script", not "body" or something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just surround the script contents in a CDATA wrapper to stop it getting eaten, like so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[
    function example() {
          var trs = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
      for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {
      }
    }
  ]]>
</script>
```