# lxml - Is there any hacky way to keep &quot;?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, lxml, elementtree

I noticed the xml entities **&quot** will automatically force to convert to their real original characters:

```
>>> from lxml import etree as et
>>> parser = et.XMLParser()
>>> xml = et.fromstring("<root><elem>&quot;hello world&quot;</elem></root>", parser)
>>> print et.tostring(xml, pretty_print=1)
<root>
  <elem>"hello world"</elem>
</root>

>>>
```

I found one related old(2009-02-07) [thread](https://answers.launchpad.net/lxml/+question/60170):

> > s = cStringIO.StringIO(""""She's the MAN!"""")
> >     e = etree.parse(s,etree.XMLParser(resolve_entities=False))
>
> Note that there's also etree.fromstring().
>
> > etree.tostring(e)
> >     '"She\'s the MAN!"'
> >
> > I would have expected resolve_entities=False to have prevented the
> >     translation of, eg, " to ".
>
> The "resolve_entities" option is meant for entities defined in a DTD
>   of which you want to keep the reference instead of the resolved value.
>   The entities you mention are part of the XML spec, not of a DTD.
>
> > is there another way to prevent this behavior (or, if nothing else,
> >     reverse it after the fact)?
>
> Well, what you get is well-formed XML. May I ask why you need the
>   entity references in the output?

Still, the response is why you want to do that, there's no direct answer to this problem. I'm quite surprised because the etree parser force the conversion without giving an option to disable it.

The following example shown why i need this solution, this xml is for [xbmc skinning](http://kodi.wiki/view/Skinning) parser:

```
>>> print open("/tmp/so.xml").read() #the original file
<window id="1234">
        <defaultcontrol>101</defaultcontrol>
        <controls>
                <control type="button" id="101">
                        <onfocus>Dialog.Close(212)</onfocus>
                        <onfocus>SetFocus(11)</onfocus>
                </control>
                <control type="button" id="102">
                        <visible>StringCompare(VideoPlayer.PlotOutline,Stream.IsPlaying) + !Skin.HasSetting(Stream.IsUpdated)</visible>
                        <onfocus>RunScript(script.test)</onfocus>
                        <onfocus>SetFocus(11)</onfocus>
                </control>
                <control type="button" id="103">
                        <visible>SubString(VideoPlayer.PlotOutline,Video.IsPlaying)</visible>
                        <onfocus>Close</onfocus>
                        <onfocus>RunScript(&quot;/.xbmc/addons/script.hello.world/default.py&quot;,&quot;$INFO[VideoPlayer.Album]&quot;,&quot;$INFO[VideoPlayer.Genre]&quot;)</onfocus>
                </control>
        </controls>
</window>

>>> root = et.parse("/tmp/so.xml", parser)
>>> r = root.getroot()
>>> for c in r:
...     for cc in c:
...         if cc.attrib.get('id') == "103":
...             cc.remove(cc[1]) #remove 1 element, it's just a demonstrate
... 
>>> o = open("/tmp/so.xml", "w")
>>> o.write(et.tostring(r, pretty_print=1)) #save it back
>>> o.close()
>>> print open("/tmp/so.xml").read() #the file after implemented 
<window id="1234">
        <defaultcontrol>101</defaultcontrol>
        <controls>
                <control type="button" id="101">
                        <onfocus>Dialog.Close(212)</onfocus>
                        <onfocus>SetFocus(11)</onfocus>
                </control>
                <control type="button" id="102">
                        <visible>StringCompare(VideoPlayer.PlotOutline,Stream.IsPlaying) + !Skin.HasSetting(Stream.IsUpdated)</visible>
                        <onfocus>RunScript(script.test)</onfocus>
                        <onfocus>SetFocus(11)</onfocus>
                </control>
                <control type="button" id="103">
                        <visible>SubString(VideoPlayer.PlotOutline,Video.IsPlaying)</visible>
                        <onfocus>RunScript("/.xbmc/addons/script.hello.world/default.py","$INFO[VideoPlayer.Album]","$INFO[VideoPlayer.Genre]")</onfocus>
                </control>
        </controls>
</window>

>>>
```

As you can see of the **onfocus** element under id "103" at the end, the **&quot** are no longer in their original form, and it lead to bug if the "$INFO[VideoPlayer.Album]" variable contains nested quotes and become ""test"" which was invalid and error.

So is it any hacky way i can keep **&quot** in their original form ?

**[UPDATE]:**
For someone who interest, the other 3 predefined xml entities, i.e. **gt**, **lt** and **amp** will only get converted by using **method="html"** and **script** tag. Either lxml VS xml.etree.ElementTree or python2 VS python3 have the same mechanism and make people confuse:

```
>>> from lxml import etree as et
>>> r = et.fromstring("<root><script>&quot;&apos;&amp;&gt;&lt;</script><p>&quot;&apos;&amp;&gt;&lt;</p></root>")
>>> print et.tostring(r, pretty_print=1, method="xml")
<root>
  <script>"'&amp;&gt;&lt;</script>
  <p>"'&amp;&gt;&lt;</p>
</root>

>>> print et.tostring(r, pretty_print=1, method="html")
<root><script>"'&><</script><p>"'&amp;&gt;&lt;</p></root>

>>>
```

**[UPDATE2]:**
The following is the list of all possible html tags:

```
#https://github.com/html5lib/html5lib-python/blob/master/html5lib/sanitizer.py
acceptable_elements = ['a', 'abbr', 'acronym', 'address', 'area',
'article', 'aside', 'audio', 'b', 'big', 'blockquote', 'br', 'button',
'canvas', 'caption', 'center', 'cite', 'code', 'col', 'colgroup',
'command', 'datagrid', 'datalist', 'dd', 'del', 'details', 'dfn',
'dialog', 'dir', 'div', 'dl', 'dt', 'em', 'event-source', 'fieldset',
'figcaption', 'figure', 'footer', 'font', 'form', 'header', 'h1',
'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'h5', 'h6', 'hr', 'i', 'img', 'input', 'ins',
'keygen', 'kbd', 'label', 'legend', 'li', 'm', 'map', 'menu', 'meter',
'multicol', 'nav', 'nextid', 'ol', 'output', 'optgroup', 'option',
'p', 'pre', 'progress', 'q', 's', 'samp', 'section', 'select',
'small', 'sound', 'source', 'spacer', 'span', 'strike', 'strong',
'sub', 'sup', 'table', 'tbody', 'td', 'textarea', 'time', 'tfoot',
'th', 'thead', 'tr', 'tt', 'u', 'ul', 'var', 'video']
from lxml import etree as et
for e in acceptable_elements:
    r = et.fromstring(e.join(["<", ">hello&amp;world</", ">"]))
    s = et.tostring(r, pretty_print=1, method="html")
    closed_tag = "</" + e + ">"
    if closed_tag not in s:
        print s
```

Run this code and you will see output as following:

```
<area>

<br>

<col>

<hr>

<img>

<input>
```

As you can see, only opening tag printed and the rest was just go into black hole. I tested all 5 xml entities and all have the same behavior. It's so confusing. This did not happen when using HTMLParser, so i guess there's buggy between fromstring(method should be default to xml) and tostring(method="html") steps. And i found it has nothing to do with entities because "< img >hello< /img >"(without entities) is truncate into < img > too(and hello just gone to nowhere, it can appear at anytime if use method="xml" to print out).

Comment: I assume there's "" in somewhere, e.g. id="101", so it's hard to determine which quotes need to keep and not. So i can't simply perform .replace for entire file or every text.

Comment: make sense, but it's gonna be after `>` and before `<` right? for a hacky way I think you need to find a pattern which you can safely do the `string.replace`, or perhaps someone may advise a better way that I'm not aware of. Good luck :)

Comment: What i can think was replace all of 2 xml predefined entities including &apos and &quot; to specific string(e.g. ANDquot;) before parsing, and then replace it back all this strings after parsed. It's ugly but it should get the job done. And i'm surprised the other 3 xml predefined xml entities(&gt;, &lt;, &amp;) doesn't converted automatically by xml etree. I'm appreciate if someone come with better idea.

Comment: From what I've noticed so far, the 3 xml predefined entities(&gt;, &lt;, &amp;) only get converted when using the method="html" and the tag must be named to "script". Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017253/python-lxml-library-fails-to-parse-lt-and-gt

Comment: so you mean the entities will not be converted if using method="xml"? doesn't make too much sense to me though, but interesting

Comment: @Anzel I've update the fact about this strange behavior.

Comment: I guess that's because with the "" or '' inside **<p>**, it's always treated as quoted text which won't be converted. And within scripts, html will treat it as **javascript** so conversion takes place, whereas xml parser doesn't care about **<script>**

Comment: Nope, actually even <hello>&gt;</hello> don't have any " or ' inside will not automatically convert too. I show all entities in one liner just for easier to demonstrate.

Comment: Really need to dive into the parser source to find out the reason, but hey good luck on this.

Answer (score 3):

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape
from lxml import etree

def to_string(xdoc):
    r = ""
    for action, elem in etree.iterwalk(xdoc, events=("start", "end")):
        if action == 'start':
            text = escape(elem.text, {"'": "&apos;", "\"": "&quot;"}) if elem.text is not None else ""
            attrs = "".join([' %s="%s"' % (k, v) for k, v in elem.attrib.items()])
            r += "<%s%s>%s" % (elem.tag, attrs, text)
        elif action == 'end':
            r += "</%s>%s" % (elem.tag, elem.tail if elem.tail else "\n")
    return r
xdoc = etree.fromstring(xml_text)
s = to_string(xdoc)
```

Comment: A bit too late to me, since I'm not working in python anymore. Nevertheless, I do a quick test with my `/tmp/so.xml` above, the `type="button" id="101/102/103"` attributes has been removed after run your code.

Comment: did fix attrs. it is not really universal solution, but could help in some cases.