# How to prevent lxml from unescaping quotes when having HTML inside XML

Tags: python, lxml

In the example below, I would like the output to contain the `&quot;Comment in quotes&quot;` like it appears in the input.

Instead, I am getting the unescaped `"Comment in quotes"` in the output. I don't see any relevant parameters that I could pass to `lxml` to prevent it from unescaping quotes.

**Minimal example:**

```
import io

from lxml import etree

xml = """\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<REQ-IF xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd" xmlns:configuration="http://eclipse.org/rmf/pror/toolextensions/1.0" xmlns:id="http://pror.org/presentation/id" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <THE-VALUE>
    <xhtml:div>
      &quot;Comment in quotes&quot;
    </xhtml:div>
  </THE-VALUE>
</REQ-IF>
"""

tree = etree.parse(io.BytesIO(bytes(xml, "UTF-8")))
output = etree.tostring(
    tree,
    doctype='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>',
    pretty_print=True,
)
print(output)
```

**Output:**

```
b'<REQ-IF xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/ReqIF/20110401/reqif.xsd" xmlns:configuration="http://eclipse.org/rmf/pror/toolextensions/1.0" xmlns:id="http://pror.org/presentation/id" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">\n  <THE-VALUE>\n    <xhtml:div>\n      "Comment in quotes"\n    </xhtml:div>\n  </THE-VALUE>\n</REQ-IF>\n'
```

**Background:**

I am implementing a generic [ReqIF parser and unparser](https://github.com/strictdoc-project/reqif) where there is a helpful `passthrough` command - the tool takes in a ReqIF file, parses it into a data model and then unparses the model back to the ReqIF file. The goal of the command is to ensure the 100% match between input and output XML files. The unescaping prevents the tool from giving a 0-diff on ReqIF XML documents that have this `&quot` symbol.

Comment: I don't think there is a clean/easy way. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/27687677/407651

Comment: Thanks. I have just checked it out based on SO's suggestion on the question I had opened :) I have contacted the developer of lxml about this topic just now.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich Why is it an issue? The value in the XML tree is the same, only encoded differently.

Comment: @Progman, thanks for asking. I have added the background.

Comment: @StanislavPankevich Is it an option to use a CDATA section?

Comment: @Progman No, I don't think the CDATA is an option because it is never in the input XML documents that I am working with.