# lxml I can't parse, and I'm getting a lot of different errors using etree.fromstring()

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, lxml

I'm trying to use the parse function of lxml and each time a different error appears. I thought the problem was on the website, but when I tried to use it on **google** and **wikipedia** it didn't work either!!

Can someone help me? If each time a different error appears, is the problem with my environment or is it with the program?

I'm running this code:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com.br/') 
data = driver.page_source
tree = etree.fromstring(data)
```

With google this error is appearing:

```
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3257, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1916, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1796, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1085, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 2
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: xmlParseEntityRef: no name, line 2, column 55
```

With wikipedia this error is appearing:

```
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3257, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1916, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1796, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1085, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 19
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 19 and head, line 19, column 57
```

And with the site I wanted the lxml to work, this error appears:

```
  File "src\lxml\etree.pyx", line 3257, in lxml.etree.fromstring
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1916, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1796, in lxml.etree._parseDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 1085, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseUnicodeDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 618, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 728, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src\lxml\parser.pxi", line 657, in lxml.etree._raiseParseError
  File "<string>", line 5
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: error parsing attribute name, line 5, column 301
```

If anyone also knows an alternative to lxml I would be grateful as well.

Comment: Why are you trying to parse html as xml?  Those are not the same.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Comment: This is duplicative of lots of questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19017253/python-lxml-library-fails-to-parse-lt-and-gt caused by people using lxml.etree when they should be using lxml.html to parse HTML. The XML subset of lxml is only for XML, not HTML.

Comment: @JohnGordon Sorry for that mistake! I managed to solve the problem thank you very much!

Comment: @Charles Duffy I found it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Gordon mentioned this is not xml, its html so you have to parse it as html.

Try this:

```
from lxml import html

driver.get('https://www.google.com.br/') 
data = driver.page_source
tree = html.fromstring(data)
```

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and the bullet point therein regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before". We get people trying to use lxml.etree for HTML on a very regular basis.

Comment: @SDAO I didn't know I was using it wrong. Thanks a lot for the explanation!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you too! I changed the title of the question to make it easier for someone who is having the same question to find the answer.